# Visual Studio can not find my header files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++

I'm struggling with problem with headers in visual studio. I tried to add specific paths but it doesn't work. Any idea why it occurs? I attached screen shot with my issue.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BA9jQ.png): [This the image of my visual studio cockpit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BA9jQ.png)

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Maybe you are updating the header files for one configuration (e.g. x64) and you compile for another one (i.e. x86.)

Comment: does the files all under same folder (in explorer)?

Comment: Right click on your project, select Properties. In VC++ Directories, at 'Include Directories', add the path where your h files reside.

Comment: are the header files "on the same level" as your source? Not in an extra directory? If so, you will have to add an "include path" in your settings

Comment: I checked and headers files are not in my "exwindow" project, but I don't know how to check where are these files. Can you help me?

Comment: Look using your OS file browser.

Comment: Man I tried to use by file explorer by I fault .  I was searching in -. C:\Users\sewer\source\repos\exWindow -E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include and wasn't there these headers. Also I want to inform if it would help , I have the most important files o disc E and something what was needed on main disc.

Comment: Only microsoft headers should be in: `E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include` you should never put anything in this location

Comment: Your headers need to be in `C:\Users\sewer\source\repos\exWindow` or you need to add additional include paths to tell your compiler where you put the headers. Also settings in Visual Studio are by default only applied to the active configuration. When you make a change make sure you either select multiple configurations or have it apply to all in the case of headers. For libraries usually debug and release will have a different library for c++ code so you must do those separately

Comment: Thank you drescherjm., I managed to solve this problem and now it' s working. But i'm wondering where are placed these headers which  are in folder "Header files" in Visual Studio since i can't find them anywhere.

Comment: If you can open the file from the "Header Files" in "Solution Explorer" I believe you can right click on the tab in the editor and click "Open containing folder". I say believe because I am not sure if that is a builtin feature or an extension  I have loaded.